Switched from ts-node to tsx for dev. I am getting module import errors for some packages using tsx, but not tsc. Can you help identify a root cause?
I am using ESM imports and tsx is unsuccessful at importing some modules.
tsc compiles successfully in NODE_ENV production and I can run the output on node 20.10.0.
tsx and NODE_ENV development (which uses ESBuild for module resolution) is not able to transpile.
I am using the same tsconfig for both.
It appears that tsx is treating some node_modules as CJS modules, and after several hours, I cannot find a resource to help me identify a root cause.
While using "type": "module" in my package.json and with this tsconfig
tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "moduleResolution": "nodenext",
    "module": "nodenext",
    "target": "esnext",
    "moduleDetection": "force",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
   ..
   }
}

This import only works with tsc, not tsx:
import { WebsocketServer } from "ws";

This hack works for both tsc and tsx, suggesting it is treated as CJS by tsx.
import * as ws from 'ws';  
const WebSocketServer = ws.WebSocketServer ?? ws.default.WebSocketServer;

Once over this hurdle, I know now see another library (not my favorite) also has trouble with imports
import { Op } from 'sequelize';

If anyone has insight into tsx and tsc ESM resolution and what might be happening here, I would like to understand this and fix it so that I don't have to use workarounds.
